# Is it possible for a view function to revert (in a loop?)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, blockchain, transactions

If I have a view function and it runs a loop to get a large set of data, is it possible to revert and be out of gas, or no matter how big the loop is will it still call it? This function will not be called internally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Usually public nodes limit view functions to the block gas limit. To protect servers from denial of service attacks.

You could run your own server and set a very high gas limit.